# Docker error permission denied and where do the images end up after pull?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have two questions.

1) I get an error when I run:

```
karl@karl-laptop:~o docker pull node
2015/04/29 01:39:41 Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/images/create?fromImage=banode&tag=: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied
```

2) When I pull down images, where are they located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission error could be due to the Docker socket being owned by root and thus either you have to use sudo or following the instructions in this link to [Create a docker group](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group)

For the default docker storage driver, aufs, the images are found in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/`, assuming the Root Dir for Docker is /var/lib/docker/aufs. You can find this out by running `docker info`.

Answer (score 2):

Add yourself to the docker group by running

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

and log out and back in

Comment: Run `sudo groupadd docker` first